# Mapbox JS - Fetching Longitude and Latitude from PHP MySql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mapbox, mapbox-marker

**RESOLVED - SEE ANSWER BELOW**

I have a MySql database called 'locationLogs' and a table called 'locations'. I have a page called map.php which shows a map (using Mapbox GLJS API). I then want to add a marker to every one of the locations in 'locations' table. The table consists of 'id', 'longitude' and 'latitude'. I then was using a while loop to attempt this. However, when going to the page, it just shows blank and doesn't load the map or anything. My code for the page is below.

```
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Live Map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .marker {
  background-image: url('mapbox-icon.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  center: [-96, 37.8],
  zoom: 3
});

// code from the next step will go here!
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "DB_USER", "DB_PASS");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("locationLogs")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM locations";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

?>


const geojson = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
      <?php
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '
    {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordintes: [' . $row['longitude'] . ', ' . $row['latitude'] . ']
        },
        properties {
            title: "Location",
            description: "A cool location",
        }
    },';
    
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
  ]
};

// add markers to map
for (const feature of geojson.features) {
  // create a HTML element for each feature
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = 'marker';

  // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
  new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates).addTo(map);
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not possible to determine where your code is failing with the information provided.  I'd suggest making sure you can get the map to initialize first (you will see a basemap that you can drag and zoom).  Once you know that's working, then  move on to the markers.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually checked if the map initialises first and it does, it works fine. When I add hard coded JavaScript markers it is also fine and the markers show, it’s when I add the PHP to show the markers, the page just doesn’t load.

Comment: @EthanScott - This Q+A sits here to help others.  Please either provide the solution or delete the Question.

Comment: @RickJames the solution is now added as an Answer... Apologies about before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-code a lot of this for it to work. I will attach the full code file below. The database structure is:

TABLE: location

id       longitude         latitude    displayName    displayDescription

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Live Map</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.2/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .marker {
  background-image: url('mapbox-icon.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mapboxgl-popup {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>

<script>

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  //style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/ethan-php/cl5v2t7fe000m14me1ihgd3z2',
  center: [-0.2792139521586705, 51.94498751258732],
  zoom: 9
});
// Add geolocate control to the map.
map.addControl(
new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
positionOptions: {
enableHighAccuracy: true
},
// When active the map will receive updates to the device's location as it changes.
trackUserLocation: true,
// Draw an arrow next to the location dot to indicate which direction the device is heading.
showUserHeading: true
})
);

// Adding markers below >>>
</script>
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
         $dbuser = 'DB_USER';
         $dbpass = 'DB_PASS';
         $dbname = 'DB_NAME';
         $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
         
         if($mysqli->connect_errno ) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s<br />", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
         }
         printf('Connected successfully.<br />');
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM location";
         
         $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
           
         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         } else {
            printf('Unexpected Error. DB did not return enough values for a successful export.<br />');
         }

?>

<script>

const geojson = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
      <?php
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $displayName = $row['displayName'];
           $displayDescription = $row['displayDescription'];
           ?>
        {
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [<?php echo $row['longitude']; ?>, <?php echo $row['latitude']; ?>]
            },
            properties: {
                title: "<?php echo $displayName; ?>",
                description: "<?php echo $displayDescription; ?>"
            }
        },
      <?php
    
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
$mysqli->close();
?>
  ]
};

// add markers to map
// Popups and Display Details
for (const feature of geojson.features) {
// create a HTML element for each feature
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';
 
// make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
.setPopup(
new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
.setHTML(
`<h3>${feature.properties.title}</h3><p>${feature.properties.description}</p>`
)
)
.addTo(map);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good indentation helps read and understand the code better